# How to get floating point determinism on Android?

Tags: java, android

In Java you can use strictfp to enforce floating point determinism across platforms. Does such an implementation exist on Android and if so how do you use it?

Comment: If you hadn't been in such a snit, you would have gotten an answer to your previous question. After you deleted it and left a snide comment, I'm not going to recreate it all for you. Short version, `strictfp` works.

Comment: @chrylis Thanks buddy! Put it in a real answer with a source so I can thumbs you up and choose you as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it just as in normal Java. Example:

```
public class TestStrictfp {
    strictfp double computeTotal(double x, double y) {
        return x + y;
    }
}
```

And use it like:

```
TestStrictfp o = new TestStrictfp();
double d = o.computeTotal(1, 2);
```

Comment: Is strictfp required on the method when you have it on the class? Also strictfp should make the calculation come out the same on AMD/Intel and all Android devices?

Comment: I removed the strictfp keyword from the class declaration to avoid confusion. What I meant is that it applies to Android as in normal Java code. As far as I understand, using strictfp guarantees that results of floating-point calculations are identical on all platforms.